# Blobs with OpenCV. Which library is best?

Tags: c++, opencv, cvblobslib

I plan to start experimenting with blobs as a C++ user, with some experience at cv::Mat's from the OpenCV.

Now the question is, which blobs library should I use if at all?

I have seen these alternatives so far:

1. [cvBlobs (on google code)](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) -- that is a c library really, working with IplImage so it needs serious adaptation to c++.
2. [CvBlobsLib (on willowgarage opencv webpage)](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib#Code%20examples) -- that looks like a c++ library but has quite bad docs with plenty of stuff left unexplained and barely any code example.
3. I have seen cv::findContours, cv::moments and cv::drawContours in the OpenCV 2.4.3 library.

What do you suggest as an expert? My pressing issue: what will the new OpenCV not cover of cvBlobs on google code?

---

Here is the link for the follow-up question on this subject, where I ask about [SimpleBlobDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13534723/1705967). You might be interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`SimpleBlobDetector` class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector) in OpenCV 2.4.  You pretty much create an object of type `SimpleBlobDetector` and then call the `detect(cv::Mat input, vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints, cv::Mat mask)` function with a cv::Mat image as input, an empty vector for keypoints, and another cv::Mat as an optional mask for a specific area of the image to look for keypoints in.

Note that the cv::Mat object has taken over image and matrix storage duty for all of the formerly separate image and matrix classes in the earlier releases of OpenCV.

Comment: OK, this answer looks exciting! I am just not sure I can make it work. I have the following concerns: this one only returns center of the blob, I can't have an entire, labelled Mat, can I? Also, how can I access the features of the detected blobs like area, convexity, color and so on? Should I pose it as a separate question and you promise me to have a look? :)

Comment: It looks now rather like a tutorial class for me with a not so mature concept, it is not very extendable either. :( Maybe I'll implement my wrapper over CBlob and I put it up opensource somewhere.

Comment: The [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#keypoint)`Keypoint` class (i.e. the output of the detect function) contains  the size as a diameter in addition to the center of each blob detected.  Also, in the constructor of the `SimpleBlobDetector`, you can specify desired colors, circularity, area, convexity, and inertia.  You just put these into the constructor as so:  `SimpleBlobDetector myBlobDetector(bool filterByArea=true, float minArea=10, float maxArea = 100);`

Comment: hang on, man, I think it is time to pop up a new question, I'll link it here so you can find it :)

Comment: I screwed up the constructor anyways.  It should be something like:                                      `cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;        params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 10.0;
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 20.0;
params.maxArea = 500.0;                                                 SimpleBlobDetector myBlobDetector(params);`

Comment: hold your horses :) and please read my updated question, you can find this new question in a link, and post your answer there. (It scores more for you anyway, for me it will be easier to read back.) This is a Q&A site where every page contains only a single, specific Q and A's to that with very brief discussions in comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the new [opencvblobslib](https://code.google.com/p/opencvblobslib/). It has great features like multi core support.

Comment: thx, +1 (and some more characters as required by SO :) )