# How to get extra information of blobs with SimpleBlobDetector?

Tags: c++, opencv, blobs

@robot_sherrick answered me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534094/1705967), this is a follow-up question for his answer.

`cv::SimpleBlobDetector` in Opencv 2.4 looks very exciting but I am not sure I can make it work for more detailed data extraction.

I have the following concerns:

- if this only returns center of the blob, I can't have an entire, labelled Mat, can I?
- how can I access the features of the detected blobs like area, convexity, color and so on?
- can I display an exact segmentation with this? (like with say, waterfall)

Comment: I'm having the same problem at the moment. Did you find a possiblity to access the contours of the blobs found by SimpleBlobDetector?

Comment: @Dobi No, unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the code should look something like this:

```
cv::Mat inputImg = imread(image_file_name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read a file
cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params; 
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 10.0;  // minimum 10 pixels between blobs
params.filterByArea = true;         // filter my blobs by area of blob
params.minArea = 20.0;              // min 20 pixels squared
params.maxArea = 500.0;             // max 500 pixels squared
SimpleBlobDetector myBlobDetector(params);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> myBlobs;
myBlobDetector.detect(inputImg, myBlobs);
```

If you then want to have these keypoints highlighted on your image:

```
cv::Mat blobImg;    
cv::drawKeypoints(inputImg, myBlobs, blobImg);
cv::imshow("Blobs", blobImg);
```

To access the info in the keypoints, you then just access each element like so:

```
for(std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>::iterator blobIterator = myBlobs.begin(); blobIterator != myBlobs.end(); blobIterator++){
   std::cout << "size of blob is: " << blobIterator->size << std::endl;
   std::cout << "point is at: " << blobIterator->pt.x << " " << blobIterator->pt.y << std::endl;
}
```

Note: this has not been compiled and may have typos.

Comment: so you are saying that there's no chance that I could extract more blob info than that? (I mean, from OOP, a class that stores these blob info and provides an iterator, like an std::map, would make more sense, and would be more flexible...)

Comment: You could certainly store the keypoints in association with a name using a std::map, but the inbuilt functions for OpenCV only recognize a std::vector.   You would have to somehow recognize each blob as belonging to a specific name like based on location, size, color, etc.  To do this, you could have a different filter for each expected type of blob.

Comment: ok, let's go back to the original question. Are you saying that you don't think there's a chance I could extract more blob info than the centre and the size?

Comment: That's just the information provided by the simple blob detector.  You can certainly extract color or area information yourself.  Color information can be extracted and averaged using your keypoint location and size and the `cv::Mat` `at` function with an iterator.  Though, rereading your question, it sounds like you want to [filter your image](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-filter2d) and analyze the results.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as the answer. It just shows how to use the simple blob detector. The OP seems to know that already. They seems to want to know how to get the value of each property used to filter the blobs.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version that will allow you to get the last contours back, via the getContours() method. They will match up by index to the keypoints.

```
class BetterBlobDetector : public cv::SimpleBlobDetector
{
public:

    BetterBlobDetector(const cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params &parameters = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params());

    const std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point> > getContours();

protected:
    virtual void detectImpl( const cv::Mat& image, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints, const cv::Mat& mask=cv::Mat()) const;
    virtual void findBlobs(const cv::Mat &image, const cv::Mat &binaryImage,
                           std::vector<Center> &centers, std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point> >&contours) const;

};
```

Then cpp

```
using namespace cv;

BetterBlobDetector::BetterBlobDetector(const SimpleBlobDetector::Params &parameters)
{

}

void BetterBlobDetector::findBlobs(const cv::Mat &image, const cv::Mat &binaryImage,
                                   vector<Center> &centers, std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point> >&curContours) const
{
    (void)image;
    centers.clear();

    curContours.clear();

    std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point> >contours;
    Mat tmpBinaryImage = binaryImage.clone();
    findContours(tmpBinaryImage, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


    for (size_t contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++)
    {
        Center center;
        center.confidence = 1;
        Moments moms = moments(Mat(contours[contourIdx]));
        if (params.filterByArea)
        {
            double area = moms.m00;
            if (area < params.minArea || area >= params.maxArea)
                continue;
        }

        if (params.filterByCircularity)
        {
            double area = moms.m00;
            double perimeter = arcLength(Mat(contours[contourIdx]), true);
            double ratio = 4 * CV_PI * area / (perimeter * perimeter);
            if (ratio < params.minCircularity || ratio >= params.maxCircularity)
                continue;
        }

        if (params.filterByInertia)
        {
            double denominator = sqrt(pow(2 * moms.mu11, 2) + pow(moms.mu20 - moms.mu02, 2));
            const double eps = 1e-2;
            double ratio;
            if (denominator > eps)
            {
                double cosmin = (moms.mu20 - moms.mu02) / denominator;
                double sinmin = 2 * moms.mu11 / denominator;
                double cosmax = -cosmin;
                double sinmax = -sinmin;

                double imin = 0.5 * (moms.mu20 + moms.mu02) - 0.5 * (moms.mu20 - moms.mu02) * cosmin - moms.mu11 * sinmin;
                double imax = 0.5 * (moms.mu20 + moms.mu02) - 0.5 * (moms.mu20 - moms.mu02) * cosmax - moms.mu11 * sinmax;
                ratio = imin / imax;
            }
            else
            {
                ratio = 1;
            }

            if (ratio < params.minInertiaRatio || ratio >= params.maxInertiaRatio)
                continue;

            center.confidence = ratio * ratio;
        }

        if (params.filterByConvexity)
        {
            vector < Point > hull;
            convexHull(Mat(contours[contourIdx]), hull);
            double area = contourArea(Mat(contours[contourIdx]));
            double hullArea = contourArea(Mat(hull));
            double ratio = area / hullArea;
            if (ratio < params.minConvexity || ratio >= params.maxConvexity)
                continue;
        }

        center.location = Point2d(moms.m10 / moms.m00, moms.m01 / moms.m00);

        if (params.filterByColor)
        {
            if (binaryImage.at<uchar> (cvRound(center.location.y), cvRound(center.location.x)) != params.blobColor)
                continue;
        }

        //compute blob radius
        {
            vector<double> dists;
            for (size_t pointIdx = 0; pointIdx < contours[contourIdx].size(); pointIdx++)
            {
                Point2d pt = contours[contourIdx][pointIdx];
                dists.push_back(norm(center.location - pt));
            }
            std::sort(dists.begin(), dists.end());
            center.radius = (dists[(dists.size() - 1) / 2] + dists[dists.size() / 2]) / 2.;
        }

        centers.push_back(center);
        curContours.push_back(contours[contourIdx]);    
}

static std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point> > _contours;

const std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point> > BetterBlobDetector::getContours() {
    return _contours;
}

void BetterBlobDetector::detectImpl(const cv::Mat& image, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints, const cv::Mat&) const
{
    //TODO: support mask
     _contours.clear();

    keypoints.clear();
    Mat grayscaleImage;
    if (image.channels() == 3)
        cvtColor(image, grayscaleImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    else
        grayscaleImage = image;

    vector < vector<Center> > centers;
    vector < vector<cv::Point> >contours;
    for (double thresh = params.minThreshold; thresh < params.maxThreshold; thresh += params.thresholdStep)
    {
        Mat binarizedImage;
        threshold(grayscaleImage, binarizedImage, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

        vector < Center > curCenters;
        vector < vector<cv::Point> >curContours, newContours;
        findBlobs(grayscaleImage, binarizedImage, curCenters, curContours);
        vector < vector<Center> > newCenters;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < curCenters.size(); i++)
        {

            bool isNew = true;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < centers.size(); j++)
            {
                double dist = norm(centers[j][ centers[j].size() / 2 ].location - curCenters[i].location);
                isNew = dist >= params.minDistBetweenBlobs && dist >= centers[j][ centers[j].size() / 2 ].radius && dist >= curCenters[i].radius;
                if (!isNew)
                {
                    centers[j].push_back(curCenters[i]);

                    size_t k = centers[j].size() - 1;
                    while( k > 0 && centers[j][k].radius < centers[j][k-1].radius )
                    {
                        centers[j][k] = centers[j][k-1];
                        k--;
                    }
                    centers[j][k] = curCenters[i];

                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isNew)
            {
                newCenters.push_back(vector<Center> (1, curCenters[i]));
                newContours.push_back(curContours[i]);
                //centers.push_back(vector<Center> (1, curCenters[i]));
            }
        }
        std::copy(newCenters.begin(), newCenters.end(), std::back_inserter(centers));
        std::copy(newContours.begin(), newContours.end(), std::back_inserter(contours));
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < centers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (centers[i].size() < params.minRepeatability)
            continue;
        Point2d sumPoint(0, 0);
        double normalizer = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < centers[i].size(); j++)
        {
            sumPoint += centers[i][j].confidence * centers[i][j].location;
            normalizer += centers[i][j].confidence;
        }
        sumPoint *= (1. / normalizer);
        KeyPoint kpt(sumPoint, (float)(centers[i][centers[i].size() / 2].radius));
        keypoints.push_back(kpt);
        _contours.push_back(contours[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that this code is very similar to the OpenCV implementation (although lacks a switch to enable contour collection). Maybe you modified OpenCV to include this contour-collecting feature or someone else did using this/your/similar code. ... But I don't think this is what the OP is asking for. I think they want the value of each property used for filtering. I think this code (the OpenCV code) can inform one how to get these properties -- either by modifying the implementation (example in my answer) or to re-calculate the values from the blob's contour.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Access SimpleBlobDetector datas for video

#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" // 
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <algorithm>

#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    const char* fileName ="C:/Users/DAGLI/Desktop/videos/new/m3.avi";  
    VideoCapture cap(fileName); //
    if(!cap.isOpened()) //
    {
        cout << "Couldn't open Video  " << fileName << "\n"; 
        return -1; 
    }
    for(;;)  // videonun frameleri icin sonsuz dongu
    {
        Mat frame,labelImg; 
        cap >> frame; 
        if(frame.empty()) break;  
        //imshow("main",frame);  

        Mat frame_gray;
        cvtColor(frame,frame_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // convert binary_image
        Mat binaryx;
        threshold(frame_gray,binaryx,120,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);


        Mat src, gray, thresh, binary;
        Mat out;
        vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;

        SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
        params.minThreshold = 120;
        params.maxThreshold = 255;
        params.thresholdStep = 100;

        params.minArea = 20; 
        params.minConvexity = 0.3;
        params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;

        params.maxArea = 1000;
        params.maxConvexity = 10;

        params.filterByColor = false;
        params.filterByCircularity = false;



        src = binaryx.clone();

        SimpleBlobDetector blobDetector( params );
        blobDetector.create("SimpleBlob");



        blobDetector.detect( src, keyPoints );
        drawKeypoints( src, keyPoints, out, CV_RGB(255,0,0), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);


        cv::Mat blobImg;    
        cv::drawKeypoints(frame, keyPoints, blobImg);
        cv::imshow("Blobs", blobImg);

        for(int i=0; i<keyPoints.size(); i++){
            //circle(out, keyPoints[i].pt, 20, cvScalar(255,0,0), 10);
            //cout<<keyPoints[i].response<<endl;
            //cout<<keyPoints[i].angle<<endl;
            //cout<<keyPoints[i].size()<<endl;
            cout<<keyPoints[i].pt.x<<endl;
            cout<<keyPoints[i].pt.y<<endl;

        }
        imshow( "out", out );

        if ((cvWaitKey(40)&0xff)==27) break;  // esc 'ye basilinca break
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted Joel's C++ to Java (since I'm working in Java). That is not an easy task since the OpenCV Java version is more than a little different from the C++ version.

I added what I wanted and what I think the OP is looking for: result values of each blob that are used for selection criteria. Not only do I get a list of blobs matching the criteria, but I can know what the values are for each blob.

The code does work ... except for convexity. It crashes hard for some reason.

I wasn't able to extend the SimpleBlobDetector. Might be possible, but I don't see much value in that. I did extend the param class which is not much value since it's a simple class of config values. But I used it as that is what Joel did and it does force the implementation to be similar to the SBD.

There are some utility classes/method that are not here, and I leave as an exercise. They are relatively easy things like calculating the hypotenuse of a right triangle.

```
package com.papapill.vision.detection;

import static com.papapill.utility.OpenCvUtil.getDistance;
import static com.papapill.utility.OpenCvUtil.roundToInt;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.papapill.support.ImageLocation;

import org.opencv.core.KeyPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfInt;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.features2d.SimpleBlobDetector;
import org.opencv.features2d.SimpleBlobDetector_Params;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Moments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Provides similar capability as {@link SimpleBlobDetector} with richer results --
 * properties of each blob that were used to select/filter.
 *
 * @implNote
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534723/how-to-get-extra-information-of-blobs-with-simpleblobdetector">See</a>
 * <p>
 * Example code passes Point to norm() to get what it calls 'dist' (which I assume is distance),
 * but in Java, norm() requires a Mat and I don't know how to convert a Point to a Mat :(
 * Computing distance is easy enough using Pythagorean theorem; and probably faster than norm().
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365900/using-opencv-norm-function-to-get-euclidean-distance-of-two-points">See</a>
 */
public final class BlobDetector {
    /**
     * Extends {@link SimpleBlobDetector} params class to include criteria of the C++ OpenV,
     * but missing from the Java version.
     */
    public static final class Criteria extends SimpleBlobDetector_Params {
        /**
         * Blob color filter.
         * See {@link SimpleBlobDetector}
         *
         * @implNote
         * This criteria seems to be excluded from the Java interface since the value is declared
         * in C++ as uchar which is not supposed in Java. It's just a byte.
         */
        private byte blobColor;
        public byte get_blobColor() {
            return blobColor;
        }
        public void set_blobColor(byte to) {
            blobColor = to;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Describes a blob.
     * Fields are immutable except for contour and keypoint since OpenCV types are mutable.
     */
    public static final class Blob {
        public Blob(
                @NonNull MatOfPoint contour,
                @NonNull KeyPoint keyPoint,
                @NonNull ImageLocation center,
                double area,
                double circularity,
                double inertia,
                double convexity,
                double size,
                byte color) {
            this.contour = contour;
            this.keyPoint = keyPoint;
            this.center = center;
            this.size = size;
            this.area = area;
            this.circularity = circularity;
            this.inertia = inertia;
            this.convexity = convexity;
            this.color = color;
        }

        /**
         * Contour representation.
         */
        public final MatOfPoint contour;

        /**
         * KeyPoint representation.
         */
        public final KeyPoint keyPoint;

        /**
         * Area in square pixels.
         */
        public final double area;

        /**
         * Point of the image that is the center of the shape.
         */
        public final ImageLocation center;

        /**
         * Color.
         */
        public final byte color;

        /**
         * Represents how convex the shape is from 0 to 1 where 1 is completely convex.
         */
        public final double convexity;

        /**
         * Represents how circular the shape is from 0 to 1 where 1 is a circle.
         */
        public final double circularity;

        /**
         * Represents how much the shape is close-loop like from 0 (line) to 1 (close-loop).
         */
        public final double inertia;

        /**
         * Size a la simple blob detector which is not intended to be precise, but can be helpful
         * to compare relative size of blobs.
         */
        public final double size;
    }

    /**
     * Internal class for collecting blob info.
     */
    private static final class BlobInfo {
        public BlobInfo(MatOfPoint contour) {
            this.contour = contour;
        }

        public final MatOfPoint contour;
        public double confidence = 1;
        public double area;
        public double circularity;
        public double inertia;
        public double convexity;
        public byte color;
        public Point center;
        public double size;

        public Blob build(Point keyPointLocation) {
            var middleBlobInfo = this;
            ImageLocation center = ImageLocation.fromCvPoint(middleBlobInfo.center);
            double radius = middleBlobInfo.size;
            MatOfPoint contour = middleBlobInfo.contour;
            KeyPoint keyPoint = new KeyPoint((float)keyPointLocation.x, (float)keyPointLocation.y, (float) radius);
            return new Blob(
                    contour,
                    keyPoint,
                    center,
                    radius,
                    area,
                    circularity,
                    inertia,
                    convexity,
                    color);
        }
    }

    public BlobDetector() {
        this.criteria = new Criteria();
    }

    private Criteria criteria;

    public Criteria getCriteria() {
        return criteria;
    }
    
    public void setCriteria(@NonNull Criteria to) {
        criteria = to;
    }

    public List<Blob> detect(@NonNull Mat image) {
        var blobs = new ArrayList<Blob>();

        // convert to grayscale if not already
        Mat grayscaleImage;
        if (image.channels() == 3) {
            grayscaleImage = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        } else {
            grayscaleImage = image;
        }

        List<List<BlobInfo>> blobsBySameThreshold = detectForEachThreshold(grayscaleImage);

        // select blobs by repeatability -- number of times found over set of thresholds
        for (var blobsForSomeThreshold : blobsBySameThreshold) {
            if (blobsForSomeThreshold.size() >= criteria.get_minRepeatability()) {
                var sumPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                double normalizer = 0;
                for (var blobForSomeThreshold : blobsForSomeThreshold) {
                    sumPoint = PointUtil.plus(sumPoint, PointUtil.times(blobForSomeThreshold.center, blobForSomeThreshold.confidence));
                    normalizer += blobForSomeThreshold.confidence;
                }
                sumPoint = PointUtil.times(sumPoint, 1.0 / normalizer);
                BlobInfo middleBlobInfo = blobsForSomeThreshold.get(blobsForSomeThreshold.size() / 2);
                blobs.add(middleBlobInfo.build(sumPoint));
            }
        }

        return blobs;
    }

    /**
     * Returns blob-info for each contour that satisfies the selection criteria -- for each
     * threshold specified in the selection criteria.
     */
    private List<List<BlobInfo>> detectForEachThreshold(Mat grayscaleImage) {
        List<List<BlobInfo>> blobsBySameThreshold = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double thresh = criteria.get_minThreshold(); thresh < criteria.get_maxThreshold(); thresh += criteria.get_thresholdStep()) {
            Mat monochromeImage = new Mat();
            Imgproc.threshold(grayscaleImage, monochromeImage, thresh, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
            List<BlobInfo> blobsForThreshold = detectAndSelectBlobs(monochromeImage);
            List<List<BlobInfo>> newBlobs = new ArrayList<>();
            for (var blob : blobsForThreshold) {
                boolean isNew = true;
                for (var blobsForSomeOtherThreshold : blobsBySameThreshold) {
                    double distance = getDistance(blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.get(blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.size() / 2).center, blob.center);
                    isNew =
                            distance >= criteria.get_minDistBetweenBlobs() &&
                                    distance >= blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.get(blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.size() / 2).size &&
                                    distance >= blob.size;
                    if (!isNew) {
                        blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.add(blob);
                        int k = blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.size() - 1;
                        while (k > 0 && blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.get(k).size < blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.get(k-1).size) {
                            blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.set(k, blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.get(k-1));
                            k--;
                        }
                        blobsForSomeOtherThreshold.set(k, blob);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isNew) {
                    var item = new ArrayList<BlobInfo>();
                    item.add(blob);
                    newBlobs.add(item);
                }
            }
            blobsBySameThreshold.addAll(newBlobs);
        }
        return blobsBySameThreshold;
    }

    /**
     * Finds contours in the image and adds a blob-info for each that satisfies the selection criteria.
     */
    private List<BlobInfo> detectAndSelectBlobs(Mat monochromeImage) {
        var blobInfos = new ArrayList<BlobInfo>();
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat tmpMonochromeImage = monochromeImage.clone(); // why clone??
        Imgproc.findContours(tmpMonochromeImage, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        for (var contour : contours) {
            BlobInfo blobInfo = new BlobInfo(contour);
            if (addBlobInfoIfSelected(blobInfo, contour, monochromeImage)) {
                blobInfos.add(blobInfo);
            }
        }
        return blobInfos;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the attributes of a contour, caches them into blob-info and returns true if all
     * attributes satisfy the selection criteria.
     * If not selected, then returns false when some of the blob-info attributes may not be loaded.
     */
    private boolean addBlobInfoIfSelected(BlobInfo blobInfo, MatOfPoint contour, Mat monochromeImage) {
        Moments moments = Imgproc.moments(contour);

        // filter on area
        if (criteria.get_filterByArea()) {
            double area = moments.m00;
            if (area < criteria.get_minArea() || area >= criteria.get_maxArea()) {
                return false;
            }
            blobInfo.area = area;
        }

        // filter on circularity
        if (criteria.get_filterByCircularity()) {
            double area = moments.m00;
            MatOfPoint2f contoursMatOfPoint2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
            contoursMatOfPoint2f.fromArray(contour.toArray());
            double perimeter = Imgproc.arcLength(contoursMatOfPoint2f, true);
            double circularity = 4 * Math.PI * area / (perimeter * perimeter);
            if (circularity < criteria.get_minCircularity() || circularity >= criteria.get_maxCircularity()) {
                return false;
            }
            blobInfo.circularity = circularity;
        }

        // filter on inertia
        if (criteria.get_filterByInertia()) {
            double denominator = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(2 * moments.mu11, 2) + Math.pow(moments.mu20 - moments.mu02, 2));
            double eps = 1e-2;
            double inertia;
            if (denominator > eps) {
                double cosmin = (moments.mu20 - moments.mu02) / denominator;
                double sinmin = 2 * moments.mu11 / denominator;
                double cosmax = -cosmin;
                double sinmax = -sinmin;

                double imin = 0.5 * (moments.mu20 + moments.mu02) - 0.5 * (moments.mu20 - moments.mu02) * cosmin - moments.mu11 * sinmin;
                double imax = 0.5 * (moments.mu20 + moments.mu02) - 0.5 * (moments.mu20 - moments.mu02) * cosmax - moments.mu11 * sinmax;
                inertia = imin / imax;
            } else {
                inertia = 1;
            }

            if (inertia < criteria.get_minInertiaRatio() || inertia >= criteria.get_maxInertiaRatio()) {
                return false;
            }

            blobInfo.confidence = inertia * inertia;
            blobInfo.inertia = inertia;
        }

        // filter on convexity
        if (criteria.get_filterByConvexity()) {
            MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();
            Imgproc.convexHull(contour, hull);
            double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
            double hullArea = Imgproc.contourArea(hull);
            double convexity = area / hullArea;
            if (convexity < criteria.get_minConvexity() || convexity >= criteria.get_maxConvexity()) {
                return false;
            }
            blobInfo.convexity = convexity;
        }

        blobInfo.center = new Point(moments.m10 / moments.m00, moments.m01 / moments.m00);

        // filter on color
        if (criteria.get_filterByColor()) {
            byte blobColor = criteria.get_blobColor();
            Mat.Atable<Byte> pixel = monochromeImage.at(byte.class, roundToInt(blobInfo.center.y), roundToInt(blobInfo.center.x));
            byte pixelColor = pixel.getV();
            if (pixelColor != blobColor) {
                return false;
            }
            blobInfo.color = pixelColor;
        }

        // calculate a size
        {
            List<Double> distances = new ArrayList<>();
            Point[] contourPoints = contour.toArray();
            for (Point contourPoint : contourPoints) {
                double distance = getDistance(blobInfo.center, contourPoint);
                distances.add(distance);
            }
            Collections.sort(distances);
            double medianA = distances.get((distances.size() - 1) / 2);
            double medianB = distances.get(distances.size() / 2);
            double average = (medianA + medianB) / 2.0;
            blobInfo.size = average;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```