# using opencv norm function to get euclidean distance of two points

Tags: c++, opencv

The test code is simple:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        cv::Point2f a(0.f, 1.f);
        cv::Point2f b(3.f, 5.f);
        std::cout << cv::norm(a - b)<< std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

It works fine. But if I change the line
`std::cout << cv::norm(a - b)<< std::endl;`
to  `std::cout << cv::norm(a, b)<< std::endl;`
or `std::cout << cv::norm(a - b, cv::NORM_L2)<< std::endl;`
error occurs and it tells me that such function cannot be matched.
I don't understand why `Point2f` type cannot be converted since the only input parameter `a-b` works well.
The opencv norm function given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#double%20norm(InputArray%20src1,%20int%20normType,%20InputArray%20mask)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the doc, the `norm()` set of functions all operate on the generic `InputArray` datatype. So, from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray), you can see that this can be either a `cv::Mat` or `std::vector` but certainly not `cv::Point2f`.

After checking in the sources (of 3.0, but I doubt it was different in 2.4 series), I see that that function has 9 overloads, but the only ones with `cv::Point<>` only have one argument.

So you will need to to convert your points to `cv::Mat`. This can be done easily, as there is a constructor for `cv::Mat` that takes a point as argument. So just do:

```
std::cout << cv::norm( cv::Mat(a), cv::Mat(b) ) << std::endl;
```

But as a side comment, I am not sure that this is the best solution: it implies additional memory allocation, and it is probably faster to compute the distance directly (i.e.: `sqrt( (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y) )`. It seems harsh, but you can rely on the compiler to optimize that.

Comment: can you give me the exact function declaration and explain it more specifically? Thank you~

Comment: @Daniel I edited the question, does that sound better ? Or what function declaration do you need ?

Comment: Thank you again! I think it is fine. If you can provide the declaration of cv::norm function with 9 overloads and explain it slightly, it would be better.

Comment: Sure I could do that, but I don't think this would add any value to the question. This is heavily templated code and anyway you can fetch them by downloading a tarball of the source and setting up a project with your favorite IDE. If you have any question on a given overload, I suggest you open another question. Else, you can accept the answer, as it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, `sqrt( (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y) )` is the same as saying `sqrt( (a - b).x * (a - b).x + (a - b).y * (a - b).y )`, so you can call `cv::norm(a - b)`.

However, according to this (albeit old) [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14188/calc-eucliadian-distance-between-two-single-point/), performance is poor for single point pairs.

I just ran the [test code](https://github.com/sturkmen72/opencv_samples/blob/master/14188-calc-eucliadian-distance-between-two-single-point.cpp) on my machine. It generates 15,000 points and calculates the distance from each to the remaining points.

```
a : [0, 0] - b : [2.14748e+09, 2.14748e+09]

euclideanDist : 3.037e+09
distanceBtwPoints : 3.037e+09
cv::norm : 3.037e+09

max_distance euclideanDist : 3.02456e+09 time passed :0.165179
max_distance distanceBtwPoints : 3.02456e+09 time passed :0.259471
max_distance cv::norm : 3.02456e+09 time passed :0.26728
```

Surprising. The fastest code is

```
float euclideanDist(cv::Point2f& a, cv::Point2f& b)
{
    cv::Point2f diff = a - b;
    return cv::sqrt(diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y);
}
```

Using `cv::norm(a - b)` and the code below are nearly equal:

```
static double distanceBtwPoints(const cv::Point2f &a, const cv::Point2f &b)
{
    double xDiff = a.x - b.x;
    double yDiff = a.y - b.y;

    return std::sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));
}
```

But that's evidently because of the casts to `double`. If left as `float`, `distanceBtwPoints` is as fast as `eucledianDist`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use:

```
#include <cmath>  // hypot

std::hypot((a - b).x, (a - b).y);
```